# After tsserver has been restarted, VS Code shows errors only for open file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I use workspace for typescript (React app) in VS Code. With each restart of the tsserver, VS Code shows errors only for the file that was open at the time of the restart. All the rest - no errors. With what can it be connected? For example, if index.tsx was open, VS Code shows errors for it. If I close index.tsx, open app.tsx, and then restart tsserver, IDE will show errors for app.tsx, but index.tsx and all others will be shown w/o errors.

The bundle always compiles without errors.

My **.settings** file:

```
{
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
},
"eslint.validate": [
    "javascript",
    "typescript"
],
"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules\\typescript\\lib", // Use Workspace Version for using plugins from tsconfig
"typescript.enablePromptUseWorkspaceTsdk": true,
"typescript.tsserver.experimental.enableProjectDiagnostics": true,
"typescript.tsserver.log": "verbose"
}
```

[image]

**UPD**:
Found a temporary solution. I have created an empty **dummy.ts** file on one level with tsconfig. When VS Code is launched, and if any .tsx file is open, errors are shown in it (as I wrote earlier). Then I close the open tsx. Open the dummy.ts. Restarting the server (**Ctrl + P -> TypeScript: Restart TS Server**). The errors are gone. I can't explain why this is happening.

Comment: I am assuming that you want vscode to show all the errors in your typescript files regradless of the files are opened or not?

Comment: This is useful, but it's a little different. I will explain differently. If the index.tsx file is open, and I select VS Code's version, errors for all tsx files will be displayed. Then, I change Typescript version to Workspace version. Errors disappear for all tsx files, but are shown only for the open index.tsx. At the same time, when opening any other files, no errors will be shown. Plz see added screenshot